# How to export Storyboard Controls

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, export, scene

I have some code (class and Storyboard Scene) that I've built in an XCode project.  I now want to reuse some of these but the only way I can think of doing this is to copy the class files (.h/.m) and basically redesign the entire View all over again.

I'm sure there must be a better way, but I can't think how.

The alternative is to have the widgets in the Scene build up programmatically, but then I don't have a visual view of it.

Answer (score 2):

This was easier than I thought:

I simply open the project in XCode that contains the scene and 'Copy' the scene.
I then go to the project I want to use it in and 'Paste'.

Answer (score 0):

The trick behind this is,
First copy the classes you need and past it, after that copy the storyboard scene which connect to these classes and past, this way you do not need to make any connection between storyboard and the VC Classes.